# If $X$ is an integrable random variable and that $A$ is an event, how to show $E(X|A) = E(X|\mathbb{1}_A)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X$ is an integrable random variable and that $A$ is an event. How can I show that $E(X|A) = E(X|\mathbb{1}_A)$? Is this something that is taken by definition?

Comment: What is your source for this (wrong) identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that $A$ is an event with $0<P(A)<1$ so that
$$
\mathrm{E}[X\mid A]:=\mathrm{E}[X\mathbf{1}_A]/P(A)
$$
as well as $\mathrm{E}[X\mid A^c]$ are well-defined.

The identity in your post is in fact wrong but instead we have the following
$$
\mathrm{E}[X\mid \mathbf{1}_A]=\mathrm{E}[X\mid A]\mathbf{1}_A+\mathrm{E}[X\mid A^c]\mathbf{1}_{A^c}.
$$
To show this identity you have to show that the right-hand side (let's call it $Y$) satisfy the criteria for being a conditional expectation of $X$ given the random variable $\mathbf{1}_A$. That is, we need to show that $Y$

1. is $\sigma(\mathbf{1}_A)$-measurable,
2. is integrable,
3. satisfies $\int_B Y\,\mathrm dP=\int_BX\mathrm dP$ for all $B\in\sigma(\mathbf{1}_A)$.

This should be more or less straightforward once you've realized what $\sigma(\mathbf{1}_A)$ looks like.

Comment: Actually the identity is wrong (real number vs random variable).

Comment: Thanks @Did. I was too fast and forgot what happens on $A^c$.

Answer (score -3):

It is not *exactly* true.   However, yes, everything is basically definitional.

$\mathsf E[X\mid A]$ is the (conditional) expected value of $X$ when event $A$ occurs.   This is *a constant*; a real value (assuming $X$ is a real valued random variable).

$\mathsf E[X\mid \mathbf 1_A]$ is the conditional expectation of $X$ measured against the indicator random variable of $A$.   This is *a random variable*.   That means it is a function of the support of the indicator random variable.  $$\mathsf E[X\mid \mathbf 1_A]~:~\{0, 1\}\mapsto \Bbb R$$

Thus the first expected value is actually that function evaluated with an argument of $1$.   Also the evaluation at $0$ has similar meaning.

$$\mathsf E[X\mid A] = \mathsf E[X\mid \mathbf 1_A](1) \quad = \mathsf E[X\mid\mathbf 1_A{=}1]\\ \mathsf E[X\mid A^\complement] = \mathsf E[X\mid \mathbf 1_A](0) \quad = \mathsf E[X\mid \mathbf 1_A{=}0]~~$$

Comment: thanks, if I may ask, what is the best way to view what event $A$ is? I know its not a random variable or constant but am not sure if it is a set either.

Comment: An event is a set of outcomes; a subset of the sample space.

Comment: $\mathrm{E}[X\mid\mathbf{1}_A]$ is a random variable itself and hence it's defined on the same space as $X$ and $\mathbf{1}_A$ are and not $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Indeed! This answer is confusing the random variable $E(X\mid\mathbf 1_A)$, defined on $\Omega$ (as every conditional expectation $E(X\mid Y)$ for random variables $X$ and $Y$ on $\Omega$ with $X$ integrable), with the function $u$ defined by $u(y)=E(X\mid\mathbf 1_A=y)$, defined on the range of $\mathbf 1_A$, namely, on $\{0,1\}$.